# JSF 2.0 + Primefaces: Find all child components of a certain type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have several different primefaces dialogs and I've implemented a close listener which receives a `org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent`. Inside of this close event I can access the UI component which generated the close event, `org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog`.

The problem I have is that I need to access all of the input fields which are on the dialog. These input fields may be buried inside other components on the dialog. Does anyone know of an easy way (one method call) to retrieve all of the child components which are input fields recursively?

Comment: I don't think there is any convenience method that does exactly what you are looking for. But may be you can use the `getChildren` method and filter as you iterate through the list. http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I was able to come up with on my own:

```
private void doStuffToInputFields(UIComponent component) {
    if (component instanceof UIInput) {
        UIInput source = (UIInput) component;

        //Add your custom logic here to do stuff with your input fields

        return;
    }

    Iterator<UIComponent> children = component.getFacetsAndChildren();

    if (children != null) {
        UIComponent child = null;

        while (children.hasNext()) {
            child = (UIComponent) children.next();
            resetInputFields(child);
        }
    }
}
```